# use sed to remove lines in a file except the multiple patterns defined

Tags: linux, bash, sed

```
#!/bin/bash  #general

Remove this line

echo armada  #dev

Remove me also  #malfunction
```

I have a file like above. I want only lines with `#general` and `#dev` to remain.

I tried `sed -i '' '/#dev/!d' starter.sh` but this will only retain lines with `#dev`

I tried `sed -i '' '/#dev/!d;/#general/!d' starter.sh` but this will remove all.

I wonder if it's possible to retain both `#general` and `#dev` using sed

**TAKE NOTE:** I am using Mac

Comment: Try `'/#\(dev\|general\)/!d'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this `sed`:

```
sed -E '/#dev|#general/!d' file
```

```
#!/bin/bash  #general
echo armada  #dev
```

Or if you want blank lines to keep then use:

```
sed -E '/^[[:blank:]]*$|#(dev|general)/!d' file
```

Comment: The problem is if you use `sed -i "" "/#dev|#general/!d" starter.sh`. The file becomes blank

Comment: `sed -i '' -E '/^[[:blank:]]*$|#(dev|general)/!d' file` didn't make file blank and stored filtered data in file. If you're using `gnu sed` then use: `sed -i -E '/^[[:blank:]]*$|#(dev|general)/!d' file`

Comment: The file becomes blank because you forgot the `-E` option. Equivalently, you can change `|` to `\|` and omit the `-E` (which isn't properly portable anyway).

Comment: @tripleee: `-r` is not portable but `-E` is supported in all the `sed` versions I have come across (BSD, gnu etc)

Comment: I tried `sed -i -E '/#dev|#general/!d' starter.sh`. `starter.sh` became blank then a new file was created which is `starter.sh-E` and inside the file is my original file with no changes

Comment: That's because you still need the empty parameter to `-i ''`.  The command `sed -i -E` says to create a backup file with the suffix `-E`; `-i ''` says no suffix, so don't create a backup.

Comment: I can't repro with `sed -E '/#dev|#general/!d' <<<$'hello\ntest #dev\ndeleted\nanother test #general'`on MacOS High Sierra (no explicit `--version` option but the `sed` manual page says Diomidis Spinellis 2005); it prints the two lines I expect.

Comment: I just found out that using `sed` without `-E` to test the results in terminal is different

Comment: `sed -E -i '' '/#dev|#general/!d' starter.sh`. This did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

The `!d` action says "anything which doesn't match this address should be deleted".  You want to refactor the logic to say "skip this" for each matching address, then delete whatever remains.

The `b` "branch" action skips the remainder of the script for the current line (and proceeds to process the next line from the beginning of the script if there are lines remaining).

```
sed -i -e '/#dev/b' -e '/#general/b' -e 'd' starter.sh
```

As an aside, modifying a shell script seems misdirected. You have an entire programming language at your disposal; why not use it to decide which parts of the script to execute?

```
#!/bin/sh

case $1 in
 '--dev' | '--general') ;;
 *) echo 'Execute this if not run with --dev or general' >&2 ;;
esac

echo armada

case $1 in
 '--malfunction') echo 'This too' >&2;;
esac
```